# binaryjs client crashes when server restarts

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using [**binaryjs**](https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs) to implement a video transfer program between node.js server and [node-webkit](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js) client.The client stays connected,once a video is uploaded,the client starts downloading it.

It works fine generally,the client does get the videos.**But the client throws an error and crashes when the server restarts or crashes.** I have been listening the BinaryClient 'error' & 'close' event,however it doesnot works.

I guess **maybe i'd listen 'error' event from something else**.What to do to fix the problem?Anyone can help?

Thanks a lot!

**app.js:**

```
var BinaryServer = require('binaryjs').BinaryServer;
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(3000);

var binaryServer = new BinaryServer({ server: server, path: '/binary' });
binaryServer.on('connection', function (client) {
  // client on stream
  // client on close
  // client on error
});
// binaryServer on error
```

**client:**

```
var BinaryClient = require('binaryjs').BinaryClient;
var binaryClient = new BinaryClient('ws://127.0.0.1:3000/binary');
binaryClient.on('open', function () {
  // binaryClient.createStream( ... )
});
// binaryClient on stream
// binaryClient on close
// binaryClient on error
```

**error:**

```
Uncaught node.js Error 

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:742:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:541:26)
```

Comment: This project is no longer maintained, at least since a year. The domain with the docs doesn't even exist anymore. I would not bother with this library and look for a replacement.

Comment: Thanks, @LorenzMeyer Yes,it's two years since last commitment.I find the docs in 'doc' directory. I may look for a replacement if i can't solve this problem.Any suggestions about this?